# Preventing from saving "placeholder"

Tags: javascript, forms, html

I have a simple HTML form with and input:

```
<input placeholder="Default text" name="title" />
```

I have JS function that checks if input's value is empty, if so it fills it with placeholder's value (for non Webkit browsers). Now I would like to prevent saving placeholder's value, so I have written a function like this:

```
$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).submit(function (event) {
        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            var default_value = $(this).attr("placeholder").replace(/\r/g, "");
            if ($(this).attr("type") != "password" && $(this).attr("type") != "submit") {
                if (default_value == $(this).val()) {
                    $(this).attr("name", "");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

which basically removes the "name" attribute from the input. I added `preventDefault()` because I had no better idea what could be an issue except that form is sent before I clear name. I thought it will do the trick but somehow the default value is still saved.

Comment: `even.preventDefault()` together with `unbind` and `submit` part looks redundant to me. Why do you want to remove the `name` attribute instead of `val("")` and not allowing empty values to be saved?

Comment: because for some strange reason val("") does not work there. It just does not change value to "". Even if it did, I could store empty value instead of not storing at all

Comment: `placeholder` is supported in non-WebKit too, isn't it?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note: placeholder is supported by Firefox 4+, Opera 11+, Chrome 3+, and Safari 3+. Internet Explorer will begin support in version 10. So, if you're writing a shim, remember that you don't have to shim against the supporting user agents.

The code you've posted will remove the element's `name` attribute if the value is equal to the default value. I don't think this is what you mean... don't you want to instead blank out the value if it is equal to the default value?

```
if (default_value == $(this).val())
    $(this).attr("name", "");
// should be...
if (default_value == $(this).val())
    $(this).val('');
```

Also, there are several placeholder shim scripts already around for jQuery... check one out and consider using it, or see how they handle form posting and take note. [Here's one of many](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html).

---

**Edit**
There are a few other problems in your script, it is causing javascript errors and not completing. If you're using Firebug to debug, try turning on the "Persist" option in console when you're working with forms to preserve errors between requests.

The problem is, you're checking for placeholder text *before* checking to see that the element is of a type that will even *have* placeholder text. See below for the fix.

```
$('form').each(function () {
    $(this).submit(function (event) {
        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr("type") != "password" && $(this).attr("type") != "submit") {
                var default_value = (
                    $(this).attr("placeholder") ?
                    $(this).attr("placeholder").replace(/\r/g, "") :
                    false
                );
                if (default_value && default_value == $(this).val()) {
                    $(this).attr("name", "");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a8DQS/

---

**Edit 2**

For those not using jQuery, this is the plain javascript way to do the same thing the OP's jQuery code does:

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
var frm_ct = forms.length;
for (var x = 0; x < frm_ct; x++) {
    var handler = function (e) {
        var elements = this.elements;
        elmnt_ct = elements.length;
        for (var y=0; y < elmnt_ct; y++) {
            if (
                elements[y].tagName == 'INPUT' && (
                    elements[y].type != 'password' &&
                    elements[y].type != 'submit'
                )
            ) {
                var default_value = (
                    elements[y].placeholder ?
                    elements[y].placeholder.replace(/\r/g, "") :
                    false
                );
                if (default_value && default_value == elements[y].value)
                    elements[y].value = '';
            }
        }
    }
    if (forms[x].addEventListener)
        forms[x].addEventListener('submit', handler, false);
    else
        forms[x].attachEvent('onsubmit', handler);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDLZJ/2/

Comment: hi, thanks for the answer. For strange reason it does not want to clear the value at the point where i do .val(). I think I just do it too late. I have used one of the many functions available, I am just extending its behaviour a little bit. I have no idea why .val() does not work - i think it is the key to solve my mystery - in other places there is no problem with it. What could possibly prevent .val() from being executred? COuld the form be already sent?